# How do you refer to this kind of shirts?

Tags: single-word-requests

What are some of the more common ways to refer to these shirts?

[image]

[image]

How common are the terms "Hawaiian shirt", "summer shirt", "Miami Vice short sleeved shirt", etc. to refer to them? Which one of them is the most common in American English?

Let me thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: I'd  say 'Hawaiian' but I'm not from US.

Comment: I'd say "Hawaiian" and I am from the US.

Comment: I can't speak for the rest of the country, but in California, they're Hawaiian shirts, even if the pattern isn't strictly Hawaiian.

Comment: Generally,, "Hawaiian" implies a colorful shirt with a floral pattern, usually rich in reds and yellows.  The first shirt is a reasonable example, and the 4th would at least pass.  The other two are more questionable.  "Loud" is another term that basically implies a pattern bordering on obnoxious, without being specific.

Comment: In the technical vocabulary of the fashion industry, these shirts are characterized as 'loud'.

Comment: #2 and #3 resemble [Reyn Spooner shirts](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=ZdtoW9iIK_Cc_QbPgp_IDA&q=reyn+spooner+shirts&oq=Reyn+Spooner&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0l10.1890.4805.0.7089.13.7.0.5.5.0.204.753.0j4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.10.930.0..0i131k1.0.g0cSw5mh0CU), and they are definitely Hawaiian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modern Hawaiian shirt, known in Hawaii as the [aloha shirt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloha_shirt), was first marketed in Waikiki in the mid-1930s and soon became wildly popular all over the islands, especially with surfers and tourists. Sporting a large, bold floral print in silk or cotton and designed with a straight hem to be worn untucked, the fashion soon moved to the US mainland:

> Even Charlie McCarthy sports a top hat and white tie. But not Bing [Crosby]: He'll stick to the [*Hawaiian shirt*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SCEN19371224.1.9&txq=%2522Hawaiian+shirt%2522)... — *Santa Cruz Evening News*, 24 Dec. 1937.

A Hawaiian shirt and porkpie hat became Bing Crosby’s trademark, even beyond the tropical road movies with Bob Hope, also fond of wearing a Hawaiian shirt, and Dorothy Lamour in the inevitable sarong.

[image]

The fashion also spread to Australia:

> …John had on a most attractive [Hawaiian shirt](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/131902488?searchTerm=%22Hawaiian+shirt%22), patterned all over in native design carried out in pastel shades. — *The News* (Adelaide), 3 Jan. 1938.

American soldiers who served in the Pacific brought the shirt home from the war, and when mass tourism to Hawaii became accessible to middle income Americans in the 1950s, it became a ubiquitous souvenir. Television shows like Hawaii Five-O, Magnum PI, and Miami Vice also popularized the look. And of course there was Elvis:

[image]

And even President Truman, in a more subdued — but rather wrinkled — print:

[image]

*Hawaiian shirt* is by far the most common term for the garment (1121 hits in the [iWeb corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/)) followed by the name on the islands: *aloha shirt* (253 hits). A summer shirt could be any short-sleeved shirt, either casual or dress, of any material or style, and it wasn’t the stars of Miami Vice who first made the shirts popular in Florida and elsewhere.

The predominantly black and white shirt you included in your question might pass for a tropical print, but there aren’t enough colors to earn the sobriquet “Hawaiian.”

Comment: Solid answer, except in regard to the black-and-white (and green) shirt. When I lived on Oahu about a decade ago, that style (more subdued colors, often monochrome, in a frame-pattern) predominated for everyday business wear, and based on [Reyn Spooner's current product line](https://www.reynspooner.com/collections/men-short-sleeve-shirts) it's still quite common. It might not look colorful enough to mainlanders to be a "Hawaiian" shirt, but it is most definitely an *aloha* shirt.

Comment: I guess it is green; I thought it was grey. I just remember the mostly red  shirt (silk) and matching kimono-ish dress from my maternal grandparents' trip to Hawaii  in the early 60s. I don't think they ever wore them after the trip.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic term for these is "Camp Shirt". "Bowling Shirt" is another way to find a similar cut, but without the flowery patterns.

Comment: Some supporting evidence would make this a better answer. A link to Tori Richard, say.